# Uppercase letters should come first in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have some data like ...
Mango,
apple,
Banana,
carrot

I am looking for elastic search sort query which should give the result as Capital letters should come first like below

Banana,
Mango,
apple,
carrot

Can anyone please help me how to prepare query for this requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the `keyword` field and sorting data in `asc` order, you will be able to get your desired result.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "apple"
}
{
  "name": "Banana"
}
{
  "name": "Mango"
}
{
  "name": "carrot"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65624606",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Banana"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Banana"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "65624606",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Mango"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Mango"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "65624606",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "apple"
        },
        "sort": [
          "apple"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "65624606",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "carrot"
        },
        "sort": [
          "carrot"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks ASCII ! It would be interesting to explain how to achieve the opposite, i.e. lowercase first :-)

Comment: @Venu did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 